# Catch all the monkeys on a tree (Graphs)

Tags: graph-algorithm

I got this question in a recruitment test a few days ago. I basically could not do anything -

We are given a tree(tree is a connected graph where every pair of nodes have a single simple path between them) with n nodes(also edge length between nodes), and a starting node where we have a monkey catcher with a constant speed of 1 unit/sec. Monkeys are very agile with an arbitrarily large speed(infinite speed) and are trying to avoid the catcher. They are aware of each other's positions and try to maximise the total time it takes for the catcher to catch them. Catcher is trying to minimise this time.
If at a moment of time a monkey and the catcher are at the same position, the monkey is caught, however many are there.
We have to find the time it takes for the catcher to catch all of them.

Edit - We are also given the number and starting nodes of all the monkeys.

From Sergio's comment - I forgot to clarify that monkeys know the catcher and each other's positions and the catcher knows all the monkeys's positions at all times.

Please help

Comment: The problem is underspecified, I think. If the monkeys can travel both up and down the tree, are aware of catcher's position and are intelligently trying to evade it (moving at infinite speed), then, at best, it'll take undetermined amount of time to catch them all. At worst, the catcher will never be able to catch them all.

Comment: Hi Sergio. On what basis are you saying this? the graph is a tree, so there is no way a monkey can escape if the catcher decides to go after it, even if they have infinite speed, they will have to cross the catcher and will get caught. This is my understanding, please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Imagine a tree with three branches, A, B and C (for simplicity, the main branches are straight, don't have additional branches). The catcher goes down A and catches all monkeys in it. Then it returns to root and goes down B. In the meanwhile, all the monkeys in C relocate to A, so when the catcher goes down C, it won't find any monkeys. It can retry A, but what if the monkeys are all in B now (moved while the catcher was in C)? It's a matter of chance now, and the catcher's chances get worse as the tree gets more branches.

Comment: I dont understand how this is a matter of chance after he returns to root? Maybe I explained the question poorly, but when the catcher returns to root, then it can target whichever branch it wants, catcher also has the full info of which monkeys are where since he can see them. Lets say he chooses a single monkey to catch at a time, then I dont think there is any scenario where that particular monkey can evade capture(since this is a tree, so cant have cycles). He can catch them all one by one like this.

Comment: After having explored C and still not having caught all the monkeys (assuming it knows how many are there), it has to choose where to retry, A or B. If it guesses right, it caches the monkeys. If not, the monkeys hiding in the other branch may relocate.

Comment: Hi Sergio, I have made an edit. Catcher is also aware of positions of all the monkeys.

Comment: Ah, that's an important point. With this info, the catcher should be able to get them all _eventually_, but off the top of my head, I can't estimate this time.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help.

Comment: The problem is phrased ambiguously. You might want to provide a small example to illustrate the underlying data structure, the algorithm monkeys would follow to evade capture for the most time, and the algorithm the catcher might use to catch them all in the shortest time possible. For example, if you mean monkeys are going through "nodes" to indicate it is climbing a tree with no escape possible and one tree was 1,000 units tall while another one was 1 unit tall with a total of two monkeys, the catcher would spend about 2,000 units catching the first monkey

Comment: You could also have strategies like if 3 monkeys where in 3 trees with 2 being extremely tall and one being short, you would need to climb the trees from least tall to most tall, because if you, for example, did it in reverse, you'd catch one at 1,500 tall, on your way up the 1,200 tree, the monkey in the tree of height 5 could climb up the tallest tree. That'd be about 1,500 + 1,500 + 1.200 + 1,200 + 1,500 (ending with the catcher being at the top of the tallest tree), because the monkey at the height of 5 would go up the 1,500 tree as he climbed the 1,200 tree.

Comment: Hi @user904963, the question is on graph theory. Trees are special graphs, which have only one simple path between any pair of nodes. We have a single tree having n nodes and neither monkeys, nor the catcher can go outside it.

Comment: Are you saying each node can only have two edges? Are there any guarantees on the length of a chain of nodes? This problem seems impossible, because you specified that each node has two edges, so the monkey can always escape as the catcher is slowly walking through one edge in an effort to catch one monkey. If there are some nodes with only one edge going to them, the algorithm I described above must be central to answering the question - you have to catch the closest monkeys first since, while you go up another long one, a monkey on a short one can go up a higher tree where he caught one.

Comment: Without knowing constraints on the graph (like the number of nodes in each path from the root node to a leaf node. I'm assuming the problem statement specified some kind of rule like there are two that are twice as long as the third path in a graph with three paths. Otherwise, the best you can do is try to derive the worst configuration, apply the algorithm I gave you, and figure out the worst case performance.

Comment: Also, are all edges the same number of units (so you can deal with just nodes and calculate (number of nodes in a path - 1)/(1 unit/s) = number of seconds transpired.

Comment: Hi, I am using the general definition of a graph - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(abstract_data_type)#:~:text=In%20computer%20science%2C%20a%20graph,of%20graph%20theory%20within%20mathematics. Please note that the tree is a special type of graph. I have also written in the question that the length of each edge is given in a unit. And the speed of catcher is 1 unit/sec, while that of monkeys in infinite.

Comment: I think you can significantly clarify the question by giving at least one or two sample input and outputs of the algorithm..